# compare my current directory to a predefined directory in unix

Tags: unix, command-line, path

I'm trying to write a small script that will install extensions for the [cms](http://www.symphony-cms.com) I currently use.  However, when I `ssh` into my box, I don't want to always want to see if i am in the correct directory to install my extensions.  Instead, I would like to just run a command and in that command it checks the current working directory and then compares the end of that directory to the one i predefine.

for example, I install my extensions in, you guessed it, the `extensions` folder.  Say i run `pwd` and it spits out `/home/site.com/not_extensions_directory/`.  Then the script would see that the current directory is not the `extensions` one so then I can kill the install and print out a warning.

An even better solution would be having the script detect that I am not in the correct directory and then give a user prompt for

`would you like to switch to the "extensions" directory to continue installing (yes/no)?`

what would the correct syntax be for doing this on a unix box (either solution)?

Comment: @shellter - this doesn't happen on login.  It's something that i run if i'm setting up a new site instance.  I'm not sys admining this box completely since that is out of my league ATM (and prob in the future =X).  Also, i may want to expand this if i'm installing new extensions in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Put this at the top of your script.  Replace `/path/to/extensions` with your `extensions` folder.

```
CURRENT_DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "$0" )" && pwd )"

if [ $CURRENT_DIR != /path/to/extensions ]; then
    echo "This script needs to be run from /path/to/extensions"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: this is a good start...was trying something more dynamic b/c I have multiple sites with different folder paths to the `extensions` folder.  however, I am getting this warning when I do an `echo` on `$CURRENT_DIR`: `dirname: invalid option -- b. Try dirname --help' for more information.`

Comment: You have run the shell fragment as-is under a bash login shell.  `$0` expands to "-bash" (set by sshd), which dirname understands as a clustered option group of options it doesn't support, beginning with "-b".